# Proof that $(n \cdot q^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a null sequence for $q \in \mathbb{C}:\lvert q \rvert \lt 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $q \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\lvert q \rvert \lt 1$ and $a_n = n \cdot q^n$.

I need to show that $(a_n)_n$ is a null sequence. I am able to show this for $q \in \mathbb{R}$ but how do I proof it for $q \in \mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $|x|\to 0\iff x\to 0$. So take absolute values and let $|q| = x\in\Bbb R$. Then you have

$$b_n =|n||q|^n = n|q|^n=nx^n$$

which is the sequence of real numbers you desired.